# Shuffling Four Kinds of Each Two Cards So That None of Them Remains in the Same Place

Tags: combinatorics, card-games, derangements

I am asking for your help with solving the problem.

I encountered this problem in a blog post about derangements. The author of the blog stated the answer is $297$.

I solved by tree diagram for $1$, $2$, and $3$ kinds. ($0$, $1$, $10$ ways) Then I proceeded to solve in the same method. But there were too many branches. So, the tree diagram doesn't seem to be the right idea. How should I proceed?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read its title.

Comment: I don't quite understand... are you saying that there are eight cards, for two numbers and one card of each suit for each number? And are you looking for how many ways you can do this with any set of cards?

Comment: I have read the posting's title and I still am not $100\%$ sure what the question is.  A good rule of thumb, for presenting Math ideas, is to assume that your target audience is a room containing $30$ teenagers, each of whom is a freshman Math major.  You want to communicate in such a way that on average, $(27)$ of the $(30)$ teenagers will be perfectly clear on the idea(s) that you are trying to communicate.

Comment: Re previous comment, this typically requires that you proofread your communication, let the communication filter down into your subconscious, and then proofread it again.  You are attempting to find any portion of your communication that would not immediately be crystal clear to $90\%$ of your audience.

Comment: Seems like you're looking at https://oeis.org/A000459 – lots of links there.

Comment: @Mathemagician314  Suppose you have two each of A,K,Q,J of spades and deal them in order.  This is the number of patterns which do not have any Aces in positions $1$ and $2$, no Kings in positions $3$ and $4$, no Queens in positions $5$ and $6$, and no Jacks in positions $7$ and $8$.  The total number of possible patterns including prohibited ones is $\frac{8!}{2^4}=2520$

Comment: @Henry Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My interpretation: how many ways are there to permute the string "AABBCCDD" in such a way that no letter A will stand on first or second place,  no letter B not third or fourth spot, no letter C on fifth or sixth spot and no letter D on one of the last two spots.

Number the spots with $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$.

For $i=1,2$ let $A_i$ denote the set of permutations such that on spot $i$ a letter A is placed.

For $i=3,4$ let $B_i$ denote the set of permutations such that on spot $i$ a letter B is placed.

For $i=5,6$ let $C_i$ denote the set of permutations such that on spot $i$ a letter C is placed.

For $i=7,8$ let $D_i$ denote the set of permutations such that on spot $i$ a letter D is placed.

Then to be found is:$$\frac{8}{2!2!2!2!}-|A_1\cup A_2\cup B_3\cup B_4\cup C_5\cup C_6\cup D_7\cup D_8|$$

Working this out with the principle of inclusion/exclusion and symmetry we find:

$$2520-8\left|A_{1}\right|+4\left|A_{1}A_{2}\right|+24\left|A_{1}B_{3}\right|-24\left|A_{1}A_{2}B_{3}\right|-32\left|A_{1}B_{3}C_{5}\right|$$$$+6\left|A_{1}A_{2}B_{3}B_{4}\right|+48\left|A_{1}A_{2}B_{3}C_{5}\right|+16\left|A_{1}B_{3}C_{5}D_{7}\right|$$$$-24\left|A_{1}A_{2}B_{3}B_{4}C_{5}\right|-32\left|A_{1}A_{2}B_{3}C_{5}D_{7}\right|+4\left|A_{1}A_{2}B_{3}B_{4}C_{5}C_{6}\right|+24\left|A_{1}A_{2}B_{3}B_{4}C_{5}D_{7}\right|$$$$-8\left|A_{1}A_{2}B_{3}B_{4}C_{5}C_{6}D_{7}\right|+\left|A_{1}A_{2}B_{3}B_{4}C_{5}C_{6}D_{7}D_{8}\right|$$

Beware that e.g. $|A_1A_2B_3C_5|=\frac{4!}{0!1!1!2!}$.

The final outcome appears to be:$$2520-5040+360+4320-720-1920+36+576+384-72-192+4+48-8+1$$$$=297$$